# how to share pictures in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

We can share information in our apps by sending emails in our app.
I don't know how to put pictures in the email body.

like this:
http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/files/2007/06/iphone_email_jenny.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good [Tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html) for How to send a picture with email.

First of all you have to Create NSData object from your PNG/JPEG image data and then implement the method as previously suggested by Jason Coco.

Answer (score 0):

Send `addAttachmentData:mimeType:filename:` to your `MFMailComposeViewController` instance.